# get_defaultViewUrl () not working in SP Hosted app

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to get the default view url of a list in SP hosted app. Below is the code i am trying, on execute success method.

```
spListobj.get_defaultViewUrl();
```

It is returning me this error : **The property or field 'DefaultViewUrl' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.**

Then ss, the error suggests i include the **DefaultViewUrl** property while loading the List object as:

```
ctx.load(spListobjCollection, 'Include(Title,BaseTemplate,DefaultViewUrl,ItemCount)');
```

**Edit**: I am loading the listCollection together and using enumerator to get individual list .
But still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

The proper syntax for loading [SP.List.defaultViewUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557895%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
context.load(list,'DefaultViewUrl');
```

Working example

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);   
context.load(list,'DefaultViewUrl');   
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
      console.log(list.get_defaultViewUrl());    
   }, 
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
   }
);
```

**Update**

Since `DefaultViewUrl` property is available for a List object, you have to specify explicitly to load this property:

```
context.load(list,'DefaultViewUrl');
```

The line:

```
ctx.load(listItems, 'Include(DefaultViewUrl)');
```

is incorrect since it tells to load `DefaultViewUrl` property from [ListItem object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee552478%28v=office.14%29.aspx), which in turn does not contain such a property.

Example 2

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);   
var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

context.load(items);   
context.load(list,'DefaultViewUrl');  //explicitly specify to load  DefaultViewUrl property of List object
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
      for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count();i++) {
         var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);
         console.log(item.get_fieldValues());
      }   
      console.log(list.get_defaultViewUrl());    
   }, 
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
   }
);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. my bad i copied wrong code as i am, loading list collection together and then using enumerator to get each list.

Comment: The answer has been updated

Comment: Basically, specifying ctx.load(listItemsCollection, 'Include(DefaultViewUrl)') is incorrect since it tells to load DefaultViewUrl property from ListItem object, which in turn does not contain such a property

Comment: i am loading list collection not listitem collection