# How to get library url in the below piece of code

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am working on the task which retrieves all the subsites from the site collection and its lists and libraries names and its url to bind in  the div.I got all worked but i didn't get url of the document library which should be bind as a URL in the list name so that we can navigate to the libraries by clicking it.I posted my code below any help would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {    

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',getAllWebs);    
    });    

    function getAllWebs(success,error)    
{    
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
   var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();    
   var level = 0;    
   jQuery("#tonydashboard").empty();    
   var html4 ="<div class='tab'>";    

   var getAllWebsInner = function(web,success,error)     
   {    
      var ctx = web.get_context();    
      var webs = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);     
      //var webs = web.get_webs();    
      ctx.load(webs,'Include(Title,Webs,ServerRelativeUrl,Lists)');    
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(    
        function(){    
        for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){    
           var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);    
           var webtitle = web.get_title();    
           var weburl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl();    
           jQuery("#tonydashboard").after("<div id='"+webtitle+"' alt='"+webtitle+"' style='display:none'></div>");    
           this.listColl= web.get_lists();    
           var listEnumerator = this.listColl.getEnumerator();    
          while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {    
            debugger;    
            var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();    
            listInfo = 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' BaseType: ' +     
            oList.get_baseType() + '\n';    
            //var listFullUrl = window.location.origin + oList.get_defaultViewUrl();    
            var siteTitle=web.get_title();    
            var listTitle=oList.get_title();    

            $("[id='"+siteTitle+"']").append("<div onclick='window.open('newurl.html','mywindow');' style='cursor: pointer;'>"+listTitle+"</div>");    
            console.log(listInfo);    
         }    

        //var html3="<button class='tablinks' onclick='openCity(this)'>"+webtitle+"</button>";    
        var html3="<input id='btnSearch' class='tablinks' type='button' onclick='openCity(this)' name='"+webtitle+"' value='"+webtitle+"'>";    
        jQuery("#tonydashboard").append(html3);    
                   if(web.get_webs().get_count() > 0) {    
                   getAllWebsInner(web,success,error);    
                }       
            }    
         },    
        error);    
   };    

   getAllWebsInner(web,success,error);     
jQuery("#tonydashboard").append('</div>');       
}    
</script>    

<div id="tonycontent">    
    <!-- Dashboard -->    
    <div id="tonydashboard" class="tonycontenttable">    

    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your code i can see you have used `oList.get_defaultViewUrl();`to get the URL of the List but this property does not come with web object. You will receive this error

`uncaught Error: The property or field 'DefaultViewUrl' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

you need to specifically load the List including DefaultViewURL and executequery after that you will be able to get this Property.

```
context.load(olist,'DefaultViewUrl');   
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
      var ListURL=olist.get_defaultViewUrl());    
   }, 
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
   }
);
```

For ref [get_defaultViewUrl () not working in SP Hosted app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105691/get-defaultviewurl-not-working-in-sp-hosted-app)